# Finding the shortest path in a complex data structure with looping nodes

Tags: python, json, traversal, tree-traversal, graph-traversal

Here is an example of the data structure I have stored in JSON:

```
{
    "alpha": {
        "node1": "echo",
        "node2": "bravo"
    },
    "bravo": {
        "node1": "alpha",
        "node2": "bravo",
        "node3": "charlie"
    },
    "charlie": {
        "node1": "bravo",
        "node2": "foxtrot"
    },
    "delta": {
        "node1": "alpha",
        "node2": "hotel"
    },
    "echo": {
        "node1": "golf",
        "node2": "delta"
    },
    "foxtrot": {
        "node1": "echo",
        "node2": "india",
        "node3": "delta"
    },
    "golf": {
        "node1": "hotel",
        "node2": "charlie"
    },
    "hotel": {
        "node1": "foxtrot",
        "node2": "india"
    },
    "india": {
        "node1": "charlie",
        "node2": "hotel"
    }
}
```

I am looking to find the shortest path between any two nodes.  For example, the shortest path from `echo` to `hotel` is: `echo` -> `golf` -> `hotel`

As you can see, these nodes are looping and it's possible to traverse them endlessly.  I should also note that the node paths are all one way.  So using the same example above, the shortest path from `hotel` back to `echo` is: `hotel` -> `foxtrot` -> `echo`

Is there a name for a data structure like this?  I know the looping breaks the rules of a "tree".  Would this be graph traversal?

Comment: Probably BFS could help here.

Comment: what have you tried? google "graph shortest path" gives you a few links regarding typical algorithms for that.

Answer (score 1):

What you have is an [adjacency list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list). Although it is cleaner to have something like this (removing node1, node2 to make it a simple array) :

```
{
    "alpha": [
        "echo",
        "bravo"
    ],
    "bravo": [
        "alpha",
        "bravo",
        "charlie"
    ],
    ...
    "india": [
        "charlie",
        "hotel"
    ]
}
```

There are no weights/distances given so you can find shortest path with BFS. [Here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576675-bfs-breadth-first-search-graph-traversal/) is an implementation.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is a shortest path through a graph. Check this out:

http://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/algorithms.shortest_paths.html